# How do I make a method that makes the employee one year older?

Tags: java

I have just started learning to program in Java in my education. Which means, I'm still completely new to Java.

I've got some code where I should make a method called birthday() that makes the employee one year older and then show the employee's new age.

I have a class called Employee.java and a class called EmployeeApp.java.

The Employee.java code looks like this:

```
package model;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private boolean trainee;
    private int age;


    public Employee(String inputName, int inputAge) {
        name = inputName;
        age = inputAge;
        trainee = true;
    }


    public void setName(String inputName) {
        name = inputName;
    }

    public void setAge(int inputAge) {
        age = inputAge;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int birthday() {
        agePlusOne = age + 1;
    }

    public void setTrainee(boolean isTrainee) {
        trainee = isTrainee;
    }


    public boolean isTrainee() {
        return trainee;
    }

    public void printEmployee() {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Trainee: " + trainee);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The EmployeeApp.java code looks like this:

```
 package model;

 public class EmployeeApp {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("Hans Jensen", 23);
        e1.printEmployee();
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Rasmus Nielsen", 32);
        e2.printEmployee();

   }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :-)

Comment: `public int birthday() {
   return ++age;
}`

Comment: Please format code as code.

Comment: but how to print/show the new age in the console right after the age?

Comment: What do you mean "new age"? There is only one age here, and you only call `print` once, and never call `birthday()`;

Comment: how to call the method birthday() in EmployeeApp.java and display the new age which is the age + 1?

Comment: where is **agePlusOne** declared????

Comment: If you don't store the employee's date of birth, how do you know when to call `birthday()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public int birthday() {

        return age++;
}
```

After this now in printEmployee() method add a line of code `System.out.println("Age+1: is"+birthday());`)

Full Code:

```
public void printEmployee() {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Trainee: " + trainee);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);

        System.out.println("Age+1: is"+birthday());//add this line
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: That's a really bad idea. If you print your employees info often enough he will get retired before the week ends...

Comment: But it meets the OP's criterion.

Comment: Well, my comment was mostly sarcastical, but you maybe want to check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) . That could be something the OP want‘s to learn about as he seems to be a beginner. So mentioning that in your answer wouldn‘t harm it.

Answer (score 1):

First you should ask yourself what is really asked of you. The way I understand it, the `birthday` method should make the employee one year older, so it should change the value of its `age` variable.

Your `birthday` function stores `age + 1` in a new variable `agePlusOne` (which is not declared and really should be) so it does the calculation but it doesn't affect the employee's `age`. You either need to store the result of `age + 1` in `age` instead or use the existing function `setAge` to do it for you (by passing it the calculation as a parameter).

Next you need to show the employee's new age. It's not very clear to me where you're supposed to do that. The thing that would make sense is to have a `birthday` function that changes the age when it is called and does no output to screen (except maybe temporarily for debugging purposes). You would show its effect in the `main` function, for instance by adding two lines of code after the existing ones:

```
// existing lines
Employee e2 = new Employee("Rasmus Nielsen", 32);
e2.printEmployee(); // shows age before calling birthday
// new lines
e2.birthday();      // changes value of age
e2.printEmployee(); // shows age after calling birthday
```

If you think you must do the output in the `birthday` function, just copy the line in `printEmployee` that shows the age.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int ageUp() {
    System.out.println(++age);
    return age;
}
```

But you shouldn't do it this way the printing should be outside the `ageUp` method.

Comment: Could you, the person who downvoted all the answers, explain why?

Answer (score 0):

well it sounds a bit obscure but instead of using an `age` field you could change your implementation into a `birthday` field...

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private boolean trainee;
    private Date birthday; //changes takes place in here
    ...

}
```

and whenever your ask for the age of the employee you refer to a certain date

```
public int getAgeInYears(Date referenceDate){
    int age = ... // some Math to calculate age - please do on your own
    return age;
}
```

in action it would look like

```
int ageOnEntrance = myEmployee.getAgeInYears(new Date(1997));
int ageNow = myEmployee.getAgeInYears(new Date(now())); 
int ageOnRetirement = myEmployee.getAgeInYears(new Date(2018));  //lucky guy
int candlesOnCakeIn2002 = myEmployee.getAgeInYears(new Date(2002)); 
int candlesOnCakeLastYear = myEmployee.getAgeInYears(new Date(2017));
```

Comment: `Date` is not a valid class in this answer - but i expect @user3740970 to be smart enough to deal with it....

Answer (score -1):

Change method `birthday()`:

```
public int birthday() {
    return ++age; //return new age
}
```

Comment: but how to print/show the new age in the console right after the age?